# javascript anonymous function have callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

//Add this to "OnDomLoad" event

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

(function(win,doc){
    var scriptElement, scrSrc;
    if (typeof (win.ClickTaleCreateDOMElement) != "function")
    {
        win.ClickTaleCreateDOMElement = function(tagName)
        {
            if (doc.createElementNS)
            {
                return doc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', tagName);
            }
            return doc.createElement(tagName);
        }
    }

    win.WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime();

    scriptElement = ClickTaleCreateDOMElement('script');

    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";

    scrSrc = doc.location.protocol=='https:'? 'https://cdnssl.clicktale.net/':  'http://cdn.clicktale.net/';
    scrSrc += 'www16/ptc/65823b2d-e976-415b-8417-8db9c9c11650.js';
    scriptElement.src = scrSrc;
    doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
})(window,document);

</script>
```

Javascript block of code, has callback function? can i put this line of code inside  $(window).on('load', function () { } ?

thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate What do you mean by _can i put this line of code inside $(window).on('load', function () { }_?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Only thing with your current code is, its a self executing function, so whenever the execution reaches the code, it will be run. if you write $(window).load() or $(document).load(), it will wait till the window or document is fully loaded.